# Is this monster level appropriate?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, monster-design

It's been a while, but I decided to take one of my *Pathfinder 1e* Dungeons and transfer it into *Pathfinder 2e*. That being said, I could not find a [Kyrana](https://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Kyrana) anywhere in the *Pathfinder 2e Bestiary*, so I took a shot at rebuilding it using the rules found in the *Pathfinder 2e Gamemastery Guide*. In my experience, a level 1 party of 2 could fight this creature, albeit with some difficulty. With that in mind, I used the metrics for a Level 1 Creature to recreate it:

> NE MEDIUM FIRE DRAGON | Creature Level 1
>
> Perception : +6|60ft Darkvision|Low-Light Vision
>
> Languages : Draconic
>
> Skills : Climb +9
>
> Str +3 | Dex +3 | Con +2 | Int -4 | Wis -1 | Cha -3
>
> ---
>
> AC 13, Fort +7, Ref +7, Will +4
>
> HP 35; Immunities: Fire; Weaknesses: Cold 5
>
> ---
>
> Speed 30ft
>
> Melee * Claws+8 | Agile (-4 to hit on second attack and -8 to hit on third attack (instead of -5/-10)) | 1D4
>
> Melee * Bite+8 | 1D4+2
>
> Breath Weapon ** Arcane, Evocation, Fire | 3D6 damage in a 20ft line (DC 13 Reflex to halve). Cannot use again until 1D4 turns later
>
> Firey Regeneration | During any turn a Kyrana would normally take FIRE damage, it gains Regeneration 10 until the end of its next turn. It cannot use its Breath Weapon on itself to activate this effect

That all being said, **Is this creature too strong for its level?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This creature has some numerical problems, but is roughly Level 2

An easy comparison is to be had with the [Fire Mephit](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=194). I'm also including the [Goblin Pyro](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=234) for some reference. Few Level 1 creatures are a good comparison when including the Breath Weapon. Included [Hippocampus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=696) as a late addition to hit on some other things relating to its physical stats. (The [Monster Filter](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFilter.aspx) can be used if you want further comparisons)

> Perception : +6|60ft Darkvision|Low-Light Vision

Mephit: +3 w/ the special ability to see through smoke. A significant difference, but other Level 1 Creatures have better Perception. Slightly high, and makes little sense with a Wisdom penalty.

> Skills : Climb +9

A large skill bonus, but in a not terribly useful/more thematic skill. Reasonable and in line with the source.

> Str +3 | Dex +3 | Con +2 | Int -4 | Wis -1 | Cha -3

Fire Mephit are 0/+4/0/-2/0/+2; although it's not as specialized, the Dragon has significant physical ability scores. Low INT and Charisma pose no significant penalty, so they do not 'balance' it. Not problematic, but again slightly high.

> AC 13, Fort +7, Ref +7, Will +4

Mephit is much more difficult to hit at AC 17, but it's Fort is an easy 3. Reflex is comparable with different Dexterity, and Mephit is higher again on Will. The AC being so low may be problematic. 13 is the *minimum AC* that player characters will have. Even 'traditionally easy to hit' Large creatures have AC around 16. Compare Hippocampus (1e: AC 12, 2e: AC 16). With +3 Dexterity, it makes no sense to have less than 16 AC.

> HP 35; Immunities: Fire; Weaknesses: Cold 5

Clearly intended to counter-balance the low AC, this creature's HP is far and above others at level 1. Mephit has 16, even the Hippocampus (Large, +4 Con) only has 24. Immunity is fine, even at level 1, but the Weakness could be lower if the HP is reduced. By the book, it should be 3 maximum.

> Speed 30ft

This is exceptionally quick for 2e, where you can potentially move twice and still attack (or use your Breath Weapon, etc). The 1e Kyrana was not exceptionally fast, so this should be 25ft.

> Melee * Claws+8 [+4,+0] | Agile | 1d4
> Melee * Bite+8 [+3,-2] | 1d4+2

This block makes less sense in 2e than it did in 1e. The +2 damage should be static across the attacks. +8 is slightly high and 1d4+2 is slightly low, making these fairly balanced if you include that +2.

> Breath Weapon ** Arcane, Evocation, Fire | 3d6 damage in a 20ft line (DC 13 Reflex to halve). Cannot use again until 1d4 turns later

By this point you're probably wondering how I can say so matter-of-factly that this creature isn't suitable for Level 1. Well, the details are in the Special Abilities. This breath weapon is roughly equivalent to a 3rd level spell. 3d6 is the definition of a Limited Use area ability for Level 2. The DC being low doesn't really make sense (again) and "balances" this out, but is very swingy. (Also, the Save would be "basic Reflex" to allow for completely avoiding or taking double damage). 3d6, on an unlucky save, would completely decimate level 1 PC's (who usually have 15-20 HP), and potentially more than 1 at a time. Bring those numbers in a little bit to balance it out. Not terrible as written, definitely has the potential to be a scary moment in the fight.

> Firey Regeneration | During any turn a Kyrana would normally take FIRE damage, it gains Regeneration 10 until the end of its next turn. It cannot use its Breath Weapon on itself to activate this effect

Alright This ability is just bonkers. This should not exist. The Fire Mephit gets Fast Healing **2**. 10 HP is almost as much HP as most of the Level 1 creatures, and it's *also* Regeneration. Drop this to Fast Healing 3 or Regeneration 2. It will make more sense with lower health (did you mean Regeneration 1? Because that would make more sense).

---

What I'd recommend:

- Option 1: Reduce its Breath to 2d6 and reduce its fiery regeneration as noted, drop about 10 HP but increase its AC by about 2-3 for a hefty Level 1 creature
- Option 2: Reduce the power on its fiery regeneration as noted and increase it's AC to make it a solid-to-light Level 2 creature

Comment: Thanks for all the input! I spread out the ability scores and evened out the other statistics into make my monster a bit more reasonable. Plus, your two suggestions gave me the idea to have Adolescent and Adult stat-blocks for it; after they defeated this creature at the start of the dungeon, they either discover or are informed that it isn't a full grown adult and it's likely that its clutch-mates will emerge from a nearby mine. From there, the dungeon revolves around sealing the tunnels and discovering other shtuff happening inside

Comment: That sounds like a lot of fun. Happy Pathfinding